# RnR: Long running query, Heroku timeouts: webhooks? Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, webhooks

So here's the issue, we have a data that the users want displayed.  The query, we optimized and indexed to be as fast as I think its going get.  We might shave off a second or two but with the amount of data, not much we can do.

Anyway, so the query runs great when limited to a day or two of data, however the users are running it for a week or two of data.  So the query for two or three weeks of data takes about 40 seconds, with a Heroku timeout of 30 seconds, that doesn't work.  So we need a solution.

So searching here and Google, I see comments that webhooks or Ajax would work as out solution.  However, I've been unable to find a real concrete example.  I also saw a comment where someone was saying we could send some kind of response that would "reset the clock." But again sounded intriguing but couldn't find an example.

We're kind of under the gun, the users are unhappy, so we need a solution that is fast and simple.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot paginate results? I've been working with a database recently and quite a few tables have over 3 million results with complex datasets and associations. Without pagination, that would be a nightmare. If you're using mysql2 gem you might be interested in the 'stream' option: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#streaming. Sorry, I don't have a concrete example.

Comment: By the way, if this is to display data on a graph, I'd probably use AJAX callbacks and fetch the data in batches, then I'd cache that data. We need more info on how this data is being used.

Comment: that's really interesting about the streaming.  I think I can use that  somewhere else.   We do paginate, the issue is with the actual query execution time which is about 30-40 seconds.  The timeout is 30, which it not tweakable on Heroku.  So it's more about the time it takes the query to execute than the results.

Comment: Is the pagination being done on the query level with limit/offset? How many records are you fetching at a time, and how many records are there in the table(s) for this dataset? Is this data being used for graphs/plotting, or average results?

Comment: no the pagination is being done with Kaminari.  I did a quick test to see if a limit to 30 rows would speed up the query and it did but only by about a second, we need to save about 10 to be safe.

Comment: But have you checked the underlying query that kaminari is generating, or are you doing something like paginate_array? I have a table with over 2 million rows here which I paginate with kaminari at 100 rows per page and it loads in less than a second. This tells me something is up with your query. Check the logs and see if you can update your question with the query, and the kaminari call.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. I have what is essentially a 'bulk download' page in my Sinatra app, which my client app calls to import data into a local webSQL db in the browser.

The download page (lets call it "GET /download") queries a CouchDB database to get all of the documents in a given view, and it's this part of the process (much like your query) that takes  a long time.

I was able to work around the issue by using Sinatra's streaming API.  As mentioned above, you can 'reset' the clock in Heroku by sending at least one by in the response before the 30s time is up. This resets the clock for another 55s (and each additional byte you send keeps resetting the clock again), so that while you're still sending data, the connection can be kept open indefinitely.

In Sinatra, I was able to replace this:

```
get '/download' do
  body = db.view 'data/all'
end
```

..with something like this:

```
get '/download' do
  # stream is a Sinatra helper that effectively does 'chunked transfer encoding'
  stream do |out|
    # Long query starts here
    db.view 'data/all' do |row|
      # As each row comes back from the db, stream it to the front-end
      out << row
    end
  end
end
```

This works well for me, because the 'time to first byte' (ie. the time taken for the db query to return the first row is well under the 30s limit.

The only downside is that previously I was getting all of the results back from the database into my Sinatra app, then calculating an MD5 sum of the entire result to use as the etag header.  My client app could use this either to do a conditional HTTP get (ie. if it tried to download again and no data had been modified, I could just send a 302 Not Modified);  plus it could be compared against it's own checksum of the data it received (to ensure it hadn't been corrupted/modified in transit).

Once you start streaming data in the response, you lose the ability to calculate an MD5 sum of the content to send as a HTTP header (because you don't have all of the data yet; and you can't send headers after you've started sending body content).

I'm thinking about changing this to some sort of paginated, multiple AJAX call, solution;  as Zenph suggested above.  That, or use some sort of worker process (eg. Resque, DelayedJob) to offload the query to;  but then I'm not sure how I'd notify the client when the data is ready to be fetched.

Hope this helps.